# Multipart/form-data and RESTful architecture?

Tags: rest, multipart

A few times I have come across a problem where I need to create a RESTful-API, but the requirements also states that "it should be possible to upload a file using the API"..
The past few times I have solved this by simply allowing the client to send a multipart/form-data with the content of the file to my RESTful-API.. however.. thus approach sort of makes me wonder if this is the right way to do it.
The RESTful-guidelines clearly states that you should only be able to CRUD for ONE single resource, but the nature of a multipart/form-data is multiple resources (for instance, 1-many files.. or 1 file and a bunch of metadata, etc). Now I can either just simply limit the endpoint to only allow one single "content" within the multipart/form-data and then associate that with the correct url, but that would sort of break the purpose of a multipart-content-type.. or I could allow the C(R)UD-operations of multiple resources, or I could treat the whole request as one single resource (one resource that contains a file, metadata etc.. however, for a GET it would not be possible to get the same response as the content sent during the request, since as far as I know you cant GET a multipart/form-data, but you could get a single file, or a single JSON/XML etc..)
Has anyone solved this in a "neat" way that complice with both REST and doesnt limit multipart to be one single "resource"? Or should I simply not use multipart and use something else for files, and in such a way be able to seperate file uploads and "text/json/xml/etc-uploads"?

Answer (score 0):

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is an [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5).

The dominant application designed with the REST architectural constraints is the [world wide web](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm).

On the web, a common way to upload a file is to use an HTML form, with the enctype set to multipart/form-data, and also an input control with type=file.

Any general-purpose component will know the right thing to do, because all of the useful bits have been standardized - the hypermedia representation of the form (provided by the server) defines all of the parameters the client needs to construct the appropriate HTTP Request.

> The RESTful-guidelines clearly states that you should only be able to CRUD for ONE single resource

REST suffers from a lot of [semantic diffusion](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticDiffusion.html).  It can make things really confusing when you start trying to combine ideas from different authors.

REST doesn't mean CRUD -- REST means that all resources understand messages the same way.

HTTP (again, conforming to the REST constraints) defines a number of different [methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4) for clients to use when communicating intended semantics to the servers.  For remote authoring semantics GET, PUT (PATCH), DELETE are all we need to communicate remote changes to documents, but HTTP's uniform interface doesn't stop there -- we have a lot of other [methods with standards](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml).

And of course, that list includes [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3), which doesn't mean "CRUD".  The actual meaning is much closer to these [semantics aren't worth standardizing](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).